# Oracle Database service creation for jHipster Gateway in Cloud Foundry

Tags: jhipster, spring-cloud, cloud-foundry

I have a jHipster generated Gateway which is in the process of being deployed to Cloud Foundry. The registry has been deployed and is up and running.

Upon firing *jhipster cloudfoundry* from commandline, and at the time of instance startup in cloud, I see the error below:

```
    017-06-24T09:43:36.568-04:00 [APP/0] [OUT] Caused by:
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.cloud.CloudException: No unique service matching class javax.sql.DataSource found. Expected 1, found 0
```

The database definitions are provided in the Gateway-dev.yml file defined and accessible in the registry.

I have tried to follow the [spring-music example in github](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/spring-music), which details (in User provided Services section) how to create User defined Oracle service in Cloud Foundry but the same error persists.

Can someone please provide thoughts on how best to approach this or is there a working example that someone knows and can be git cloned?

Thanks!

Comment: Additionally, I have also referenced jHipster documentation pertaining to Oracle: https://jhipster.github.io/using-oracle/

Comment: Okay, looks like I have made some progress. The error I see now is `[ main] o.s.cloud.AbstractCloudConnector : No suitable service info creator found for service oracle-database-service Did you forget to add a ServiceInfoCreator?`

I am referencing [link](https://spring.io/blog/2014/08/05/extending-spring-cloud) to try and understand what may be going on.